# Printing out the exact number of characters from a 512 character data package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out how to print out exactly 3000 characters. I managed to print 2560, but I am unsure how to print the chunk of the 512 character data package.

```html
import urllib
url = raw_input('Enter an URL: ')

try:
    data = urllib.urlopen(url)
    size = 0
except:
    print ('An improperly formatted or non-existent URL')
    exit()
    
while True:
    info = data.read(512)
    if len(info)<1: break
    size = size + len(info)
    if size >= 3100: break
    print info[0:3000]
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to print one character at a time, counting each character as you print it, and stop when that counter reaches 3000.

Comment: What you want to do, is instead of just abruptly breaking when you cross 3000, you just need to get the characters needed to hit 3000, and then break. i should also mention, you can always just open the entire url in one go, and slice the string till 3000 characters.

Comment: it makes sense to use a slice method. However, even if I open the entire url, I cannot slice a string **info** till 3000 chars. Have no idea, why the output is blank (I added print info[0:3000] right after the code) Any ideas?

Comment: Prof told us to use 512 characters for a single data package. I can't change that number.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import urllib
url = raw_input('Enter an URL: ')
info = ""

try:
    data = urllib.urlopen(url)
    size = 0
except:
    print ('An improperly formatted or non-existent URL')
    exit()
    
while True:
    info = info + data.read(512) #read 512 data package
    if len(info)<1: break     
    if len(info) >= 3000: break  
print len(info[:3000])
```